# SQL - Trigger with recursion

Tags: sql-server, recursion, triggers, social-networking

I've got this problem with this exercise apologize that we insert into the table friends that at start is empty some couple of friends

Table `Friends`:

```
  +------------+------------+
  |  Friend1   |   Friend2  |
  +------------+------------+
  | Marc       | Luc        |    
  | Luc        | Marc       |        
  | Marc       | John       |
  | John       | Marc       |   
  +-------------------------+
```

The table `Relationship` at the beginning is empty

```
    +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
    |   GradeOfRelationShip          |  Friend1  | Friend2 |
    +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
    |                                |           |         |
    +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
```

After the insert of the tuple of friends I'll see something like this

```
      +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
      |   GradeOfRelationShip          |  Friend1  | Friend2 |
      +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
      |          1                     |  Marc     |   Luc   |
      |          1                     |  Luc      |   Marc  |
      |          1                     |  Marc     |   John  |
      |          1                     |  John     |   Marc  |
      +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
```

I inserted into `Relationship` only the couple of friends directly (in table `Friends` I insert only direct friends so with Grade 1)

Then I need to find all possible couple of friends from what I inserted into relationship so the output will be:

```
      +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
      |   GradeOfRelationShip          |  Friend1  | Friend2 |
      +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
      |          1                     |  Marc     |   Luc   |
      |          1                     |  Luc      |   Marc  |
      |          1                     |  Marc     |   John  |
      |          1                     |  John     |   Marc  |
      |          2                     |  Luc      |   John  |
      |          2                     |  John     |   Luc   |
      +--------------------------------+-----------+---------+
```

So what my trigger must do:

1. After the insert of a couple of friends into table `Friends` I need to check if this couple already exist into table relationship.

   - If exists with `GradeOfRelationship = 0` I need to set this `GradeOfRelationship` with the new value = 1 (now I've got a path between this friends)
   - If not exists i need to insert this tuple into the table `Relationship` with `GradeOfRelationship = 1`
2. I must search all possible path between all friend that I've inserted into `Relationship`, for do that i think that it's necessary a Join like this

   ```
   Select 
       Table1.Friend1, Table1.Friend2, Table1.GradeOfRelationship,
       Table2.Friend1, Table2.Friend2, Table2.GradeOfRelationship
   From 
       Relationship Table1 
   join 
       Relationship Table2 on Table1.Friend2 = Table2.Friend1
   ```

And the output that i think that I'll see:

```
      +-------------------+------+-----------+---------+-------+
      | Friend1  | Friend2| Lv   |  Friend1  | Friend2 | Lv    |
      +-------------------+------+-----------+---------+-------+
      |  Marc    |  Luc   |  1   |  Luc      |   Marc  |  1    |
      |  Marc    |  John  |  1   |  John     |   Marc  |  1    |
      |  John    |  Marc  |  1   |  Marc     |   Luc   |  1    |
      |  Luc     |  Marc  |  1   |  Marc     |   John  |  1    |
      +--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

So I'll be interested only with the tuple in which

```
   Table1.Friend1 < > Table2.Friend2
   and Table1.Friend1 < > Table2.Friend2 not exist in RelationShip
   Insert into Table Relationship Values (Table1.Friend1,   
        Table2.Friend2, 
    Table1.GradeOfRelationship + Table2.GradeOfRelationship)
```

So now there is the main problem, the recursive function that after every insert on table Friends will do this.
And the other problem is that i need to insert into GradeOfRelationship the minimum path between friends.
If there is not any relationship between two people i must insert into table Relationship the couple of friends with grade 0

I trying with SQL Server but at the moment i don't have any idea to how do this statement, i think that i must use some recursive function but i don't know how....i tried to write CTE but it don't work like i want

```
   With Table1 as (Select Friend1,Friend2, 0 as Level
        from Friend
        Union All
        Select F1.Friend1, Table1.Friend2, Level+1 as FriendshipLevel
        From Friend F1 join table1 on F1.Friend2=table1.Friend1
        where F1.Friend1 < > Table1.Friend2
        ) 

    Select *
    From Table1
```

This SQL query didn't work well because it start to all possible computation with friends so 0 to infinite so it go on no termination.

Thanks a lot for your cooperation and looking forward into your answer

This is the SQL Schema of both table (Table Relationship is empty because it ll populate after the enter in action of the trigger)

```
  CREATE TABLE Friends
        (`Friend1` varchar(50), `Friend2` varchar(50))
  ;

  INSERT INTO Friends
       (`Friend1`, `Friend2`)
  VALUES
       ('Luc', 'Marc'),
       ('Marc', 'Luc'),
       ('John', 'Marc'),
       ('Marc', 'John'),
       ('Alex', 'Marc'),
       ('Marc', 'Alex')
  ;

  CREATE TABLE Relationship
    (`Friend1` varchar(50), `Friend2` varchar(50),`GradeOfRelationShip`  
     int )
    ;
```

Best Regards

Comment: I would start by reading this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: We can help but you have to give us details. Also, you need to think about what you are trying to do here. When you get even 1,000 rows in your friends table the relationship table is going to get ridiculous. You are going to have so much data it won't be manageable. A recursive cte is the way to do this though.

Comment: Infact i don't want 1.000 rows into my table. Into the table relationship i need only the possible path between friend like i wrote on my post. If i have a friend in common i can have a path between two friends and the Grade will calculate like the min path for go to the 2° friend.

Comment: I think you missed my point. When you have 1,000 friend rows you are going to have around 1,000,000 rows in the relationship table. I can probably help you but you have to provide some details. ddl and sample data so I don't have to create it from your text example would be ideal. Or just go to sqlfiddle.com and create a fiddle.

Comment: i insert on post the SQL Schema of both table i don't know if is what you asked me. Well other details if i didn't write before you must consider this problem like a social network. Every Friends a node and GradeOfRelationship the path between Friends.

Comment: Do you have a link to your sqlfiddle? Without a link nobody else can see it.

Comment: Your fiddle is for mysql. Are you using mysql or sqlserver?

Comment: You really should look at normalizing these tables. What happens when you have two people with the same name?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53192 sorry i gave you the wrong link